# VS Code skips search results after replacement; can I prevent this?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code to search and replace in a document where each line contains a whole paragraph of text. When I replace, I expect the editor to go to the next search result, but instead it skips around weirdly. What is the editor doing? Can I make it do what I expect instead?

### Reproduction

1. Launch VSCodium.
2. Reload VSCodium with extensions disabled.
3. Use *New Text File* to open a blank editor.
4. Paste the following text into the editor (courtesy of [loremipsum.io](https://loremipsum.io/)).

   ```
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
   ```
5. Click the magnifying glass on the sidebar (or press Ctrl+Shift+F) to open the search view.
6. Enter `dolor` in the *Search* field.
7. Enter `domo` in the *Replace* field.

   The choice of replacement text matters. Using `-----` or `d---r` as the replacement text, for instance, leads to the expected behavior.
8. Select the first search result ("Lorem ipsum **dolor** sit amet").
9. Press Ctrl+Shift+1 twice.
10. ***Expected document state:*** the first two occurrences of `dolor` have been replaced.

    `Lorem ipsum domo sit amet,` ... `labore et domoe magna aliqua.` ... `Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit` ...

    ***Actual document state:*** the first and third occurrences of `dolor` have been replaced.

    `Lorem ipsum domo sit amet,` ... `labore et dolore magna aliqua.` ... `Duis aute irure domo in reprehenderit` ...

### Version information from *Help: About*

**VSCodium**

```
- Version: 1.83.1
- Release: 23285
- Commit: 36d13de33ac0d6c684f10f99cff352e2f58228b3
- Date: 2023-10-12T18:26:29.496Z
- Electron: 25.8.4
- ElectronBuildId: undefined
- Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
- Node.js: 18.15.0
- V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
- OS: Linux x64 5.15.0-87-generic snap
```

Comment: _excellent repro_!! I can reproduce with VS Code 1.83.1 and VS Code Insiders 1.84.0 as Snaps on Ubuntu. I don't see an open issue ticket for this [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3Asearch-replace+label%3Abug). writing one up right now.

Comment: issue ticket: [Specific inputs cause replacing single instance in Search View to skip selection past the next instance #196684](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/196684). I'll write an answer once we get more info / confirmation that it's a bug and keep the answer updated with info as things progress.

Comment: @starball, thanks so much for porting this to the issue tracker, and for testing the regex and case-sensitive modes! Wow, I was just expecting this to be a settings thing...

Comment: well, it's more of a hunch that it's a bug. I can't imagine this being intended behaviour. I could be wrong that it's a bug, but at the moment I trust my hunch. let's see what the maintainers say.

Comment: Yeah—once I started trying to reproduce it, I very quickly stopped thinking it was a straightforward behavior that might be useful to someone.